# How to prevent mouse pointer blocked symbol when we make datepicker to readonly mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the **jquery ui datepicker** for my text boxes and have marked them as readonly to prevent manual input (as suggested here). The issue I still have is that when a user brings the mouse over the text box the cursor changes to a blocked cursor image. This gives an impression to the user that he cannot do anything with that field. Although if he goes ahead and clicks upon it, he would get the datepicker and can choose a date.

**My question is :**

```
Is there a way to elegantly handle this without writing all manipulating code for the mouse cursor?
```

**Code**

```
 <input type="text" id="startdatebooking" class="form-control input-sm" style="Height: 30px" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blocked cursor image is probably defined in your css for readonly inputs - it isn't part of the datepicker interface. The way to handle this is to define css for the `startdatebooking` id:

```
#startdatebooking {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

the `!important` flag is only necessary if a higher-level inherited class also specifies the `!important` flag. You could also use an inline style, but it's really not good form to use those.